# jQuery-validation 1.9.0 and jQuery 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have set up jQuery validation on a page using jQuery 1.7.1 as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form1").validate();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <div>
            <p>
                <input id="form1input1" name="11" class="required" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="form1input2" name="12" class="required email" />
            </p>

            <input type="submit" value="Validate form 1">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The fields are validated on submit of the form, but not on blur/keyup.

If I swap out jQuery 1.7.1 for jQuery 1.3.2 then the plugin works as documented with validations on blur/keyup.

Is this a compatibility issue? I can't find any bugs/open tickets in the GitHub issue tracker https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Comment: You sure you haven't set `onfocusout: false` anywhere (including default options)?

Comment: 100% - the code is as above. In my trouble shooting process I tried `onfocusout: true` etc. no help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this combination, you **must** specify the `type`attribute on the `input`:

```
<form id="form1">
    <div>
        <p>
            <input id="form1input1" name="11" class="required" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input id="form1input2" name="12" class="required email" type="text" />
        </p>

        <input type="submit" value="Validate form 1">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/5au9m/

The plugin author (Jörn Zaefferer) suggests this is actually due to a change that happened in jQuery:

> Afaik this works fine as long as your inputs have a type attribute. While inputs without a type attribute default to text, jQuery doesn't think so and ignores them. That was the problem on the demos, see 5f4a3a5 and 9050de7.
>
> Let me know if thats also the issue you're seeing.

Source: [Issue filed on github](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/256).